# Calculating the double integral with an integration area given by a hexagon

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

The task is to calculate the simple double integral $$\iint_D xy dxdy$$ But the tricky thing is that the area of integration is given by a hexagon with all its corners on the circle $\{x^2+y^2 = 1\}$ and with a corner in the point (1,0). And this is were I can't seem to get anywere.

Comment: Use the symmetries of the domain and of the integrand function!! 
BTW it is "double" and not "dubbel" (see your previous questions).

Comment: Use the fact that you can represent a hexagon as a union of triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is $0$ by two reasons each of which would suffice alone.

1) the integrand is odd in $x $ and the domain is symmetric wrt to $x=0$.

2) the integrand is odd in $y $ and the domain is symmetric wrt to $y=0$.